# SBT is wasting lots of disk space for dependencies each build

Tags: jenkins, sbt, playframework-2.4

We have a Playframework 2.4 (with *SBT 0.13.8*) project which we build on a Jenkins.

Today, the Jenkins stopped working because his `$JENKINS_HOME` run full. I  analyzed which tool was wasting the disk space: *SBT*.

There is a folder located at

```
.sbt/0.13/dependency/module/dynamic
```

that contains quadrillions of subfolders. Each of these has one folder for each of our *Play* modules. Each of these folders contains one *JSON* `(graph.json)` file. Looks like a huge dependency graph in JSON. `16MB` each single build.

- What is the purpose of these data structures?
- Can I configure SBT to clean this files after build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is maybe this issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2014?
Then it should be fixed in sbt 0.13.9.

See: https://twitter.com/eed3si9n/status/608309137890541569